# Python - matplotlib - weighted graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, libreoffice

Is it possible to plot `weighted graphs` in python using matplotlib?. I did not find it on the matplotlib website.

if I can't do it using `matplotlib`, can I do it using something else? 
can we do it on `libreoffice`?

essentially this is how my data looks like.

```
a,b,5
b,c,10
a,c,7
```

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer:  The [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55200/good-programs-for-drawing-graphs-directed-weighted-graphs) points us an answer given by `William Stein`. all credits to him.

Here is the answer:

Try [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) - it's open source and can draw weighted directed graphs. For example:

```
A = random_matrix(ZZ,6, density=0.5)
G = DiGraph(A, format='weighted_adjacency_matrix')  # graph from matrix
H = G.plot(edge_labels=True, graph_border=True)
H.show()             # display on screen
H.save('graph.pdf')  # save plot to vector pdf for inclusion in a paper
```

Here is another given in the same page by : `Nick Loughlin`

Try [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) - it's open source and quite flexible as far as usage is concerned.

It's good at automatic layouts etc, where for example Maple would make a mess of things.