# Plotting a Path Between Nodes of Cost Matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a small Python class to create a cost matrix. I want to highlight a path between its nodes with weighted arrows. Does a library like `matplotlib` have anything that can do this? This is my code:

```
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class CostMatrix:
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.vertices = vertices
        all_nodes = range(1, vertices + 1)
        matrix = {}
        for i in all_nodes:
            for j in all_nodes:
                matrix[i, j] = 0 if i == j else randint(1, 10)
        self.matrix = matrix

    def plot(self, path):
        print("I'm Stuck!")


c = CostMatrix(10)
path = [5, 2, 4, 6, 9, 3, 1, 7, 8, 10]
c.plot(path)
```

##Edit
I want to do this in Python, not an external software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - matplotlib - weighted graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928097/python-matplotlib-weighted-graphs)

Comment: @DollarAkshay The result is exactly what I want but I want to do it in Python, not external software. I have access to Matlab and it's perfectly capable of doing it but I don't want that.

Comment: Have you already considered using [networkx](https://networkx.org) python package?